# Application is being killed while on background

Tags: android, sleep, background-process, android-lifecycle

My application sends gps updates to a API. I need my application to run in background all the time. But unfortunately, my application always end at some point while on background. I have read that when the cpu usage of the application is low, the application is will be killed automatically. I don't want this to happen. I already included a partial wake lock on my onCreate method in my application using this code:

```
 powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
 wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "MyWakeLock");
```

Then on pause:

```
protected void onPause()
 {
     super.onPause();
     onBackground = true;
     wakeLock.acquire();
     Log.w("OnPause", "OnPause");
 }
```

I really don't know how to prevent my application being killed. I also tried using full wake lock but it is deprecated. Any ideas on how will I keep my application alive on background? I never want my application to be killed while on background. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can not.

Just make sure, you persist anything that should survive after being killed.

For anything that should **run** in background, even if the app is not shown to the user:
Use a `Service` and set it into foreground mode.

Comment: Does this mean that at some point, the application will be killed?

Comment: Yes, and it's a natural thing. Android takes care of this. Read more here: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Comment: The thing is: There is no point in not killing paused activities other than caching for faster resuming. If you really want to **run** code in background, a service is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class BGService extends Service {

    private PowerManager powerManager;
    private WakeLock wakeLock;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();

        powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
                "MyWakeLock");
        wakeLock.acquire();
    }
```

call and start service in your main activity

```
public class SendSMSActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.demo);
        startService(new Intent(this, BGService.class));
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you explain what does this do to my wake lock? Thanks!

Comment: your wack lock call in service.and this service will  start background when app start.have you solved your Question or not?